# Confluence - Redirect to new name

Tags: apache, tomcat, confluence

We had confluence running in our company with the URL `https://confluence:8443`
We changed the domain name -  let's say it is `https://abc:8443`. so server, same Apache instance and it has the new name and the cert for "abc"

It runs on Apache/TomCat, we could not figure out how to make this conversion look seamless to the users, so we created port 80 on the same server (say, server A) and installed confluence certificate on it and created a redirect to

Now if a user goes to `http://confluence`, it will go to the DNS server finds server A's IP goes to the IIS, get the redirect rule and goes `https://abc:8443`.

If a user goes to `https://abc:8443`, no problems there.

but if a user goes to `http://confluence:8443` (most of the users have this bookmarked), it gets the cert error.

Can anyone please suggest a way to make this work in confluence, that is tomcat/Apache?

Thanks for your time.

Thanks,
Shiyam

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

## Option 1: Server Name Indication

If your client browsers all support it, you can configure your HTTPD to use [Server Name Indication (SNI)](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHosts), which allows the client to tell the server which host it is requesting. This assumes that you already have two distinct SSL certs for "abc" and "confluence", and that you configure the appropriate SSL certificate under each VirtualHost.

Of note is that Internet Explorer on Windows XP [does not support SNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication#Client_side), but since Windows XP has already reached End of Life, your organization hopefully no longer has any such clients.

The example from the SNI page above, for reference, is:

```
Listen 192.168.1.1:443

LoadModule ssl_module   modules/mod_ssl.so

SSLPassPhraseDialog     builtin
AcceptMutex             flock
SSLSessionCache         shmcb:/var/cache/httpd/mod_ssl/ssl_scache(512000)
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300
SSLMutex                default
SSLRandomSeed           startup /dev/urandom  256
SSLRandomSeed           connect builtin

NameVirtualHost 192.168.1.1:443

<VirtualHost 192.168.1.1:443>
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP

        SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/star.example.com.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile   /etc/ssl/star.example.com.key

        ServerName      "one.example.com"
        DocumentRoot    "/var/www/html/one"

        CustomLog       "/var/log/httpd/one-access.log" combined
        ErrorLog        "/var/log/httpd/one-error.log"

        <Directory /var/www/html>
                AllowOverride none

                Order Allow,Deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 192.168.1.1:443>
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP

        SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/star.example.com.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile   /etc/ssl/star.example.com.key

        ServerName      "two.example.com"
        DocumentRoot    "/var/www/html/two"

        CustomLog       "/var/log/httpd/two-access.log" combined
        ErrorLog        "/var/log/httpd/two-error.log"

        <Directory /var/www/html>
                AllowOverride none

                Order Allow,Deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

## Option 2: Wildcard SSL Certificate

If your server or clients do not both support SNI, but if "abc" and "confluence" are hosts on the same domain, you can also get a wildcard SSL certificate.

For example, if you obtain a wildcard cert for *.example.com, your single httpd server will be able to handle HTTPS requests for both abc.example.com and confluence.example.com without error.